# MacOS - How to segue after log in screen

Tags: swift, macos

I have a LogInViewController, and I would like it to segue to MainViewController when the user clicks the login button.The Show segue is working fine. The problem is that it creates a new window.
[image]

I want to replace the LogInViewController with MainViewController. How can you segue to the main screen after successful authentication within the same window?

I've tried including these two in the IBAction function for the log in button before the performSegue function:

```
self.view.window?.close()
self.dismiss(nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to close the window in `prepareForSegue` method

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    self.view.window?.close()
}
```